# How to assess the impact of confounding variables?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, python, ancova, confounding

Recently I performed a comparative study where the participants had to perform different tasks using two different VR interaction methods:  controllers and hand tracking. They also filled out a survey. I want to check if the answers from the survey (confounding variables) have a statistically significant impact.

From what I've read this can be achieved using ANCOVA, where I can check an impact of a confounding variable on a relationship between an dependent and independent variable. Here is an example code in Python which uses the `statsmodels` module:

```
# Fit the ANCOVA model
model = ols('dependent_variable ~ independent_variable + confounding_variable', data=data).fit()

# Extract the results
results = model.summary()
```

However the way my data is stored doesn't have a clear independent variable. Here is exmaple data from a task where you have to perform different gestures:

```
            Age     Sex  Experience using a gamepad (1-4)   Experience using a VR headset (1-4)  Experience using hand tracking (1-3)  Experience using controllers in VR (1-3) Glasses  ID_1  ID_2       Method_1       Method_2 ID_controller ID_handTracking  CorrectGestureCounter_controller  CorrectGestureCounter_handTracking  IncorrectGestureCounter_controller  IncorrectGestureCounter_handTracking
IDs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
ID_K_1_3     25  Female                                 4                                     3                                     1                                         2     Yes   K_1   K_3     controller   handTracking           K_1             K_3                                21                                  34                                   5                                     2
ID_K_4_5     19    Male                                 4                                     2                                     1                                         2     Yes   K_4   K_5     controller   handTracking           K_4             K_5                                21                                  36                                  14                                    17
```

I would want to assess the impact of `Age`, `Sex`, `Experience using a gamepad (1-4)`, `Experience using a VR headset (1-4)`, `Experience using hand tracking (1-3)`, `Experience using controllers in VR (1-3)` and `Glasses` on the differences between `CorrectGestureCounter_controller` and `CorrectGestureCounter_handTracking` or `IncorrectGestureCounter_controller` and `IncorrectGestureCounter_handTracking`. As you can see there is no column I can use as the independent variable. What should I do?

Comment: What is the question you want to answer ultimately? It's a bit difficult to give advice without more information. On the surface, it looks like you want to measure the impact of the method on something related to the number of gestures. In this case, the VR interaction method is the independent variable. But it is a bit unclear to me if the difference between CorrectGestureCounter_controller and CorrectGestureCounter_handTracking should be really your dependent variable (as in this case, the "method" variable wouldn't make sense as an independent variable, as far as I understand your dataset).